# Как открыть несколько курсоров с в цикле FETCH главного курсора?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пытаюсь прочитать курсор в процедуре, возвращаемый из другой процедуры, и хочу записать в несколько `OUT` курсоров, перебирая данные главного курсора:

```
TYPE myCursorType IS REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE getAllDetails (
            customerNumber      IN customer.customer_number%TYPE,
            accountDetailsCur   OUT pkgaccount.curAccountDetailsType,
            otherDetailsCur     OUT myCursorType) IS
    localAccountDetails   pkgaccount.curInvestmentAccount;
    outcfunds             curInvestmentAccount;
    accountDetails        pkgaccount.curAccountDetailsType%rowtype;
BEGIN
    pkgaccount.accountDetails(customerNumber,localAccountDetails);
    LOOP
        FETCH localAccountDetails INTO accountDetails;
        EXIT WHEN localAccountDetails%notfound;
        -- здесь нужно вернуть также accountDetailsCur, 
        -- перед этим надо пройтись по нему циклом и вернуть оставшиеся данные.
        -- На основе номера счета надо вернуть еще этот курсор:
        OPEN otherDetailsCur FOR
            SELECT col1, col2
            FROM othertable
            WHERE accountnumber = localAccountDetails.accountnumber;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Так как открываю курсор в цикле, он вернет только данные последней строки курсора `localAccountDetails`. Не уверен, как тут использовать `BUILK COLLECT`, чтобы собрать все записи и выполнить цикл по ним.

Также не знаю, как вернуть `accountDetailsCur` как данные OUT, чтобы в цикле можно было получить из него оставшиеся данные.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to open multiple cursors with main cursor data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63353732) от участника [@Dyapa Srikanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701571/dyapa-srikanth)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63353732

Answer (score 2):

Можно поместить один курсор в другой с помощью `CURSOR` выражения. Запрос с ним выглядит так:

```
select 1 id, cursor (
    select 99 val, cursor (
        select 'abc' str from dual) nestcur2 from dual) nestcur1 from dual;

1   {<VAL=99,NESTCUR2={<STR=abc>,}>,}
```

Таким образом, можно сделать что-то вроде этого:

```
create table item (pk primary key) as 
    select level pk from dual connect by level <= 3;
  
create table part (pk, fk) as 
    select r.lvl, item.pk from item, lateral ( 
        select level lvl from dual connect by level <= pk) r;

declare
    cursor itemcur is 
    select pk, cursor (
        select * from part p
        where p.fk = i.pk)
    from item i;
    pk int;
    partcur sys_refcursor;
    type partarr is table of part%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    parts partarr;
begin
    open itemcur;
    loop
        fetch itemcur into pk, partcur;
        exit when itemcur%notfound;
        fetch partcur bulk collect into parts;
        dbms_output.put_line ('Fetched item '||pk||' with part count '||parts.count);
    end loop;
    close itemcur;
end;
/
Fetched item 1 with part count 1
Fetched item 2 with part count 2
Fetched item 3 with part count 3
```

Но заметьте, что это означает, что так создаются вложенные циклы `JOIN`. Если только *действительно* не нужно контролировать, сколько записей код вызова получит из вложенного курсора, то лучше сделать это обычным `JOIN`.

Можно агрегировать записи подсоединяемой таблицы в JSON или во вложенную таблицу, если надо получить только одну запись из главной таблицы, например:

```
select i.pk, json_arrayagg (json_object (p.*))
from item i
join part p on p.fk = i.pk
group by i.pk;

        PK PARTS                                                           
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
         1 [{"PK":1,"FK":1}]                                               
         2 [{"PK":1,"FK":2},{"PK":2,"FK":2}]                               
         3 [{"PK":1,"FK":3},{"PK":3,"FK":3},{"PK":2,"FK":3}]
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63358774) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>